# Dead Integer Value from an Integer Pointer that targets to a Generic Pointer

Tags: c

I'm having a doubt about type pointers to generic pointers and how can interact each other by making use of the **typecasting feature**.

I'm creating two pointers: **one generic** and **one typed**.

The Generic targets to the memory location of a **character variable**.

The Typed targets to the generic pointer by typecasting it.

My problem begins when I want to print the values from the **typed pointer**.

```
fprintf(stdout,"Integer Adress: %p | Char Value: %c | Dead Integer Value: %i \n",integerPointer, *integerPointer, *integerPointer);
```

-> Integer Adress 
-> char Value

But the third one returns a dead integer value, why?
I though that it was gonna return the **ASCII value** of the **character** that is 65.

This is the **full code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char letter = 'A';

    void* genericPointer = &letter;
    int* integerPointer = (int*) genericPointer; // Typecasting

    fprintf(stdout,"Generic Adress: %p | Char Value: %c | Integer Value: %i \n",genericPointer, *(char*) genericPointer, *(char*) genericPointer); 

    fprintf(stdout,"Integer Adress: %p | Char Value: %c | Integer Value: %i \n",integerPointer, *integerPointer, *(char*)integerPointer); 

    fprintf(stdout,"Integer Adress: %p | Char Value: %c | Dead Integer Value: %i \n",integerPointer, *integerPointer, *integerPointer); 
                                                            // Why don't 65?
        return 0;
}
```

**Outputs**:

```
Generic Adress: 0x7ffc31336a77 | Char Value: A | Integer Value: 65 
Integer Adress: 0x7ffc31336a77 | Char Value: A | Integer Value: 65 
Integer Adress: 0x7ffc31336a77 | Char Value: A | Dead Integer Value: 862615361
```

Comment: Converting a char pointer to an integer pointer doesn't work because the sizes and alignments are different. You only initialized 1 byte, but when you treat it as an integer you're access 3 uninitialized bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "undefined value" in computer memory. Memory always contains some bytes, in most cases some random data from previous code.

Now, size of `char` variable is 1 byte. You are taking address of that 1 byte and coerce it to a pointer to `int`. Size of `int` is 4 bytes. There is lack of 3 bytes in that `int`. These bytes are filled with some random data. These 3 bytes of random data is why you are seeing "dead integer" and in every run it differs.

Here's some diagram to help you:

```
char dummy[3];
char letter = 'A';
int some_junk=42;
int *integerPointer = &letter;
```

[image]

You are dereferencing `integerPointer` which pointrs to `letter`. There is not enough bytes in `letter`, so the next few bytes are used which belong to `some_junk`. On my diagram these are bytes `0x41` (from `char letter`), and `0x2a`, `0x00`, `0x00` (first three bytes of `int some_junk`) all of which, in case of [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), makes integer `10817`.

All this creates your "dead integer".

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer actually points to a `char`, not an `int`. On most architectures, an `int` is the size of four characters. When you dereference it as an `int*`, it tries to read a full `int`s worth of data. On some architectures, you're already done here; if the address isn't properly aligned for an `int`, your program will crash.

On others, like yours, it picks up the `65` *and* three bytes of adjacent data from the stack in neighboring memory addresses (possibly locals, possible return addresses, possibly stack-protecting flags generated by the compiler, etc.).

You can see your original 65 in there; your system is little-endian, so the first byte read forms the lowest byte of the resulting `int`, which can be recovered by masking off the high three bytes by doing `862615361 & 0xff`, which produces `65`. The other three bytes, in hex, are `336a77` which you'll recognize from the address of your `char` in the first place (because the pointers themselves are being picked up as the neighboring memory).

In short: Don't do this. It's undefined behavior, and while it usually behaves in predictable ways on any given architecture, with optimizations turned off, it's not going to behave in a *useful* or *portable* way.